# Could we use the "je...desto/je... umso" phrase in a subjunctive mode?

Tags: phrase, subjunctive

Usually we use the *Je...desto* or *Je...umso* phrase in indicative mode. For example:

> Je höher Sie kommen, desto mehr Punkte sammeln Sie.

But could we also use it as subjunctive or conditional mode in any context? For example:

> Je stärker ich sei, desto erfolgreicher wäre ich.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly your question is about? Your second example uses two different forms of subjunctive mood (Konjunktiv I and II). What's the real question here? Whether you can ever use Konjunktiv II in the _desto_ clause? Or how the sentence must be phrased in a context of indirectness? Or ...?

Comment: dear @johnl, You're right, I see that in second example I had to use two different forms of subjunctive (Konjunktive I and II), but I didn't know exactly in which would I be able to translate it precisely in a context like: "The stronger I become, The more successful I would be.". Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can do this and say

> Je stärker ich sei, desto erfolgreicher wäre ich.

The only problem is that sentences like this require very specific contexts to be used in, otherwise they sound weired - up to the level that people think they are wrong; which they technically aren't, given the right context.

Your sample sentence uses two different forms of subjunctive, the "sei" for indirect speech, and the "wäre" for *irrealis*.

A more easily allocatable sentence would be:

> Ich mache neuerdings Krafttraining, denn mein Trainer hat mir gesagt, je stärker ich sei, desto erfolgreicher werde ich sein. (Or ... desto mehr Erfolg werde ich haben.)

This is pure indirect speech. Usually people do not use this form of indirect speech in oral communication. They would rather say:

> Ich mache neuerdings Krafttraining, denn mein Trainer hat mir gesagt, je stärker ich bin, desto erfolgreicher werde ich. (Or ... desto mehr Erfolg werde ich haben.)

This is indicative. Note that *werde* hier is not subjunctive but future! That's a bit confusing, as the indicative and subjunctive forms are identical.

In formal, written communication the use of indirect speech is standard, though.

Now for integrating also the *irreal* or *conditional* form, we have to go to great lenghts with our fantasy to come up with a scenario where such a sentence could make sense in practice.

> Ich mache neuerdings Krafttraining, denn mein Trainer hat mir gesagt, je stärker ich sei [***indirect speech***], desto erfolgreicher wäre [***conditional***] ich im Falle einer Nominierung für die Auswahlmannschaft.

This uses an additional *conditional*, and thus the *wäre* makes sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mode can also be changed in je–desto and umso–je constructions.

Let me show the differences between the modes with the personal pronoun *er* instead of the formal *Sie* first:

> **Indicative:** Je höher *er kommt*, desto mehr Punkte *sammelt er*.
>
> **Subjunctive I:** Er sagte, je höher *er komme*, desto mehr Punkte *sammle er*.
>
> **Subjunctive II:** Er behauptet, je höher *er käme*, desto mehr Punkte *sammelte er* /  *würde er sammeln*.

If we substituted *er* with the formal *Sie*, then the subjuctive-I forms of the verbs *kommen* and *sammeln* would coincide with the indicative forms. To avoid that, the subjunctive-II forms are used:

> **Subjunctive I:** Er sagte, je höher *Sie <s>kommen</s> kämen*, desto mehr Punkte *<s>sammeln</s> sammelten Sie* / *würden Sie sammeln*.

Notice that the modes in your last sentence

> Je stärker *ich sei*, desto erfolgreicher *wäre ich*.

do not [agree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_(linguistics)); *ich sei* is subjunctive I and *ich wäre* is subjunctive II. I would consider such sentences as stylisticly poor, if not incorrect.

Comment: dear @Björn Friedrich, Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. So, according to these four examples you gave, we could conjugate my second example also could follow your rule?

Comment: @Armin, regarding your second sentence, see the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Je stärker ich sei, desto mehr erfolgreich wäre ich.

Doesn't sound right. I believe it should be more something like

> Je stärker ich **bin**, desto **erfolgreicher** wäre ich.

Comment: @Iris Also sollen wir sagen "Je stärker uch werde, desto erfolgreicher wäre ich."?

Comment: I'd probably say "Je stärker ich werde, ..." but I can't tell why

Comment: @Armin, I translated my comment. My first (now deleted) comment was a "this is right/wrong" answer, but an comment, that I would say something different, but can't tell either what's the right way to day it.

Comment: dear @Iris, Thanks anyway. But could someone please say a precise answer and describe the reason?

Comment: dear @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks a lot for your answer, but could you please describe it more with a precise reference? Thanks again in advance

Comment: @Armin, I wish I could, but I am "only" a native speaker

Comment: dear @Iris, Yes, I understand. For me also I could not explain some obvious patterns in my own language. Thanks